# square matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How I can create a square matrix for a fixed dimension such that each element in this matrix is a function e.g., 
\begin{equation}
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} x & \sin x & x^2\\ 1-x & e^x & 2x & \\ \cos x & x-2 & 3x\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
so that I can use these elements in a loop?

```
dim=3;
A=zeros(dim,dim);
B=zeros(n,n,dim)
n=10;
x=2*(1:n);
h=1/n
for j=1:dim
    for i=1:n;
        B(i,i,j)=h+(here I want A(i,j))
    end;
end;
```

This is only a rough code just to clarify how I want to use the elements of $A$??

Comment: This is a bit off topic for here, really, but I can probably help you anyway. Do you want these to be functions (e.g. @(x) x) or symbolic expressions?

Comment: Functions please..

Comment: Then A will need to be a cell array instead of a matrix. You also unfortunately will not be able to do things quite the way you wrote in the snippet, but you can get close.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, can you show me a way to write @(x) to call it in a loop?

Comment: For example, A=cell(3); A{1,1}=@(x) x; A{1,2}=@(x) sin(x); etc. Then you can retrieve the elements the same way you assigned them, using curly braces.

Comment: Thank you Ian, I tried it, it works even though it makes the code more complicated..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code snippet, however, would defining $A$ as an anonymous function help?  In other words, `A = @(x) [x,sin(x),x.^2;1-x,exp(x),2*x;cos(x),x-2,3*x];`

Comment: @Kyle 's suggestion would also work, depending on how A is going to be used.